# fatal error: 'emscripten.h' file not found when running tesseract

Tags: cmake, tesseract, emscripten

Is there any way to include it manually? [this](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract-emscripten) is the project that is giving me the error.

In `config.log` i have the following lines:

```
PATH: /Users/alejandrocamba/Documents/emsdk
PATH: /Users/alejandrocamba/Documents/emsdk/upstream/emscripten
PATH: /Users/alejandrocamba/Documents/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin
```

I guess it recognized emsdk installed in my machine but i don't why doesn't it use the emscripten files in it.

How could i link it manually?

Answer (score 0):

For linux and Mac you can just search the file location using the 'find' command and then use the path you just find

`find / -name emscripten.h`  
`#include "your_path/emscripten.h"`